# Why has the word 'Existential' become so popular

Tags: reference-request

Ten to twenty years ago the word Existential hardly ever appeared in print. Nowadays it appears everywhere. Politicians, Scientists, Newscasters and everybody in between  is using it.
The following is an edit because my question was closed.
Of the following answers and comments not one person answered the original question 'Why'.
So I ask again why do so many people today insist on using the word 'existential' instead of the word 'real'.
Do they assume it makes their statements more easily understood. Is it an attempt to elevate their arguments. It takes a lot more effort to write 'existential' than it does to write 'real' so why do it?

Comment: In what context? [Existentialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism) dates from mid-1940s.

Comment: Not an answer but [interestingly it seems to have had two jumps, one when it was first popularised from the 1940s-1960s and then it plateaus for a few decades until 1995 when it sees another revival](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Existential&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) can't say why from this - just an interesting note.

Comment: @MichaelMcgarry Your question lacks any support for your claim about the frequency of the word "existential".

Comment: @MichaelMcgarry "*Ten to twenty years ago*" Only that? Proves pundits are slow on the uptake. The atomic bomb was already an existential threat to humanity well before twenty years ago.

Comment: @MichaelMcgarry "*The term existentialism (French: L'existentialisme) was coined by the French Catholic philosopher Gabriel Marcel in the mid-1940s. When Marcel first applied the term to Jean-Paul Sartre, at a colloquium in 1945, Sartre rejected it.*" https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Existentialism

Comment: I must admit I did not think I would have to prove something which I considered so obvious that I cannot be the only one to notice. The  link in the comments above provide some proof. If you choose the years 1940-2019 in google ngrams it shows the uptick in use quite clearly. There is a difference between the use in British-English as opposed  to American-English. My interest was not in proving it but why it was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the stats posted by Lio, and similar ones with the French equivalent "existentiel" (showing a peak in 1990), I will propose the hypothesis that what changed the fortunes of the word "existential" is the fall of the Berlin wall (1989) and more generally the collapse of the eastern block.

The reasoning would be that the word is strongly associated with JP Sartre, who was a communist till his death in 1980. Before 1989, using such a word in the West was a bit risqué, as it singled you out not just as "dangerously French" but also as potentially communist. Such was not anymore the case after the fall of communism. So one could use the word without raising eye brows in the 90's, a time during which the US became hegemonious and started to think in terms of "existential risks" to their hegemony.

My 2 cents anyway.

Comment: That is very interesting and informative but I am not sure that the many of the people writing essays, reports or news articles today would be sufficiently aware of the history of the word so as to affect its usage.  When I first became aware of the word back in the 1990's it always seemed to refer to a crisis. Later after 2000 I noticed it started to refer to 'risk' and later it often referred to a problem. It now just seems to have replaced the word 'real' in a lot of places.

Comment: @MichaelMcgarry People don't need to be aware of a trend in order to follow it, though.

Comment: @Olivier5 The statistics posted by Lio does not show any remarkable behaviour for the year 1989, the year of the fall of the Berlin Wall. Moreover the statistics shows a similar increase for the period 1996-2017, where the statististics ends, like for the period 1940-1968. Hence your interpretation is not supported by the statistics. - Your speculation seems totally unsubstantiated.

Comment: It is normal to see a delay between cause and effect, so the fact that the new trend started in 1990 is not as damaging as you seem to think.